# org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: nested throwable

Tags: java, jboss, dcm4che

when start jboss,always report errors:Could not create deployment: file:/E:/JobFile/dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql/server/default/deploy/dcm4chee-storescp-service.xml

```
16:25:36,017 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
    16:25:36,018 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)
    16:25:36,019 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: E:\JobFile\dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql
    16:25:36,019 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/E:/JobFile/dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql/
    16:25:36,019 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
    16:25:36,019 INFO  [Server] Server Name: default
    16:25:36,019 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: E:\JobFile\dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\server\default
    16:25:36,019 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/E:/JobFile/dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql/server/default/
    16:25:36,020 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: E:\JobFile\dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\server\default\log
    16:25:36,020 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: E:\JobFile\dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\server\default\tmp
    16:25:36,020 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
    16:25:36,230 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_14,Sun Microsystems Inc.
    16:25:36,230 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 14.0-b16,Sun Microsystems Inc.
    16:25:36,230 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows NT (unknown) 6.2,amd64
    16:25:36,732 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
    16:25:38,192 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
    16:25:38,193 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
    16:25:38,429 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
    16:25:38,429 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
    16:25:38,755 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
    16:25:38,794 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
    16:25:38,794 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
    16:25:39,871 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
    16:25:41,088 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native
    16:25:41,089 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] jbossws-3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA (build=200803312044)
    16:25:44,886 WARN  [BasicMBeanRegistry] javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException: preRegister() failed: [ObjectName='dcm4chee.archive:service=StoreScp', Class=org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.storescp.StoreScpService (org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.storescp.StoreScpService@16bd4dc2)]
    16:25:44,886 INFO  [StoreScpService] Registration is not done -> stop
    16:25:44,890 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/E:/JobFile/dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql/server/default/deploy/dcm4chee-storescp-service.xml
    org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable: (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:251)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1451)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1350)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:345)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:212)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:451)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:171)
        ... 79 more
    Caused by: javax.management.MBeanException
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.handleInvocationExceptions(ReflectedDispatcher.java:180)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:163)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1422)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1417)
        ... 84 more
    Caused by: javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException: preRegister() failed: [ObjectName='dcm4chee.archive:service=StoreScp', Class=org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.storescp.StoreScpService (org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.storescp.StoreScpService@16bd4dc2)]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:713)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:211)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        ... 94 more
    Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.handleInvocationExceptions(ReflectedDispatcher.java:176)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AttributeDispatcher.invoke(AttributeDispatcher.java:140)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:103)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.PersistenceInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.setAttribute(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:461)
        at org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.setValuesFromMBeanInfo(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:807)
        at org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.init(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:518)
        at org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:486)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.preRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:654)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:697)
        ... 99 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unkown UID Name: PrivatePhillips3DPresentationStateStorage
        at org.dcm4che.dict.UIDs.forName(UIDs.java:48)
        at org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.AbstractScpService.parseUIDs(AbstractScpService.java:716)
        at org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.AbstractScpService.updateAcceptedSOPClass(AbstractScpService.java:626)
        at org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.storescp.StoreScpService.setAcceptedOtherSOPClasses(StoreScpService.java:705)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AttributeDispatcher.invoke(AttributeDispatcher.java:136)
        ... 110 more
```

Comment: See here: Unkown UID Name: PrivatePhillips3DPresentationStateStorage

Comment: i find it, but i don't know why

Comment: I solve it! thank you! D:\dcm4chee-dcm4chee-2.19.0-SNAPSHOT-mysql\server\default\conf\xmdesc\dcm4chee-storescp-xmbean.xml
find PrivatePhillips3DPresentationStateStorge arg,and delete it!